# Nuxt/webpack build error- Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, build, nuxt.js

I'm completely new to Nuxt and Webpack, so I'm not sure quite what details I should include here, but I'm working on a VueJS project and I can't stop getting this error when I try to run a build:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/node-fetch-native/dist/index.cjs 69:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (69:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| class BlobDataItem {
>   #path
|   #start
| 
 @ ./node_modules/node-fetch-native/lib/index.cjs 1:18-46
 @ ./.nuxt/server.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/server.js
```

This error is coming from a dependency so I don't want to edit the code in the file as that isn't a great long-term solution. I've tried adding this to my webpack.config file:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

... but still nothing. I've also had some problems with package dependencies, if that has anything to do with it. Let me know if there are other details I need to include. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix! Apparently this is an error with the a Nuxt update and we have to wait for a fix, but for now you can do this:

Go into nuxt.config.js
Find build > standalone (in mine it was at the very bottom)
Change it from true to false like this:

build: {
standalone: false
}

Answer (score 0):

Because of an unusual # character at line 69, column 2, the webpack module bundler appears to be having trouble parsing the code in the node-fetch-native package, according to the error notice you provided.

You can try adding a JavaScript file loader that can handle the syntax used in the node-fetch-native package to your webpack setup in an attempt to fix this problem. You can accomplish this by including the following rule in your module.

in your `module.rules`:

```
{
   test: /\.m?js$/,
   resolve: {
     fullySpecified: false
   }
}
```